# Migrate data from one schema to another schema both belonging to different oracle databases

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How do i migrate data from one schema to another schema(the tables have also changed), both belonging to different databases, meaning i have to establish two connections. Can someone help me with inputs on how i can achieve the above functionality using JAVA.

Can i use liquibase to migrate data from one database to another, please note I have to establish two db connections since my schemas belong to different databases, also the tables design has also been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Another option: Let SQL do **all** the work, no Java needed. Lets call the databases `dbfrom` and `dbto`. Now sign in to `dbto` and create a [database link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE-LINK.html#GUID-D966642A-B19E-449D-9968-1121AF06D793). Then your task basically becomes a insert statement.

```
-- in database dbto
create database link link_to_dbfrom; 

-- ensure user has appropriate access on both databases.

-- copy data in dbfrom to dbo
insert into schema_in_dbto.table_in_dbto( column list)
  select (column list) 
    from schema_in_dbfrom.table_in_dbfrom@link_to_dbfrom;
```